# Running Fiddler as a scheduled task. Traffic not captured

Tags: fiddler

I have a machine setup to run automated tests. I have some software, including Fiddler running as scheduled tasks on start up without user required to log in.
But tests fail, since traffic is not going through Fiddler. When I log in to that machine, I can see in Task Manager Fiddler running as background process.
I've tried starting the task as my user and as System. 
Trying to figure out how to have traffic go through that fiddler instance. Thank you!

4/27 Update

So it had to do with the user that scheduled task was set to run from. After playing with it, I figured my user was set incorrectly. Now it looks like traffic goes through Fiddler, as tests are passing. But nowhere I can see the traffic. Fiddler is running as background process and I can't find the folder where it stores temp files. I have also tried setting autosave to a file every 5 minutes. And while it works when I run fiddler in UI, no sessions are saved when it runs as background process.

Comment: Do you rely on the option "Act as system proxy at start-up"? Try to manually set Fiddler as proxy in the applications you want to capture (or permanent on the Internet settings of Windows).

Comment: Thank you. I just updated the question. Looks like traffic does go through fiddler now, but I can't see the traffic itself.